# PHP Strings/Functions: Converting a string into a chain of functions

Tags: php, string, function

Having a string like

```
12345.find_user.find_last_name
```

how can i split at the charachter `"."` and convert it to a function-call:

```
find_last_name(find_user(12345));
```

and so on....could be of N-Elements (n-functions to run)....how do i do this effectivly, performance-wise also?

**Edit, here is the solution based on your replies**

thanks Gaurav for your great help. Here is my complete solution based on yours:

i protected the `foreach` with `if(function_exists($function)){` to protect the whole thing from fatal php errors, and i added a complete example:

```
$mystring =  '12345.find_user.find_last_name';

convert_string_to_functions($mystring);

function convert_string_to_functions($mystring){
    $functions = explode('.', $mystring);
    $arg = array_shift($functions);
    foreach($functions as $function){
        if(function_exists($function)){
            $arg = $function($arg);
        } else {
            echo 'Function '.$function.' Not found';
        }
    }

    echo $arg;
}

function find_last_name($mystring=''){

    return $mystring.' i am function find_last_name';

}

function find_user($mystring=''){

    return $mystring.' i am function find_user';

}
```

Comment: Please don't do that, it is just a terrible idea

Comment: i know, it is only a special case where i can only start off with strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string =  '12345.find_user.find_last_name';
$functions = explode('.', $string);
$arg = array_shift($functions);
foreach($functions as $function){
    $arg = $function($arg);
}

echo $arg;
```

Comment: So, at the end of the `foreach` loop, `$arg` will be `find_last_name(find_user(12345));`, and just writing `echo $arg;` will execute that function?

Comment: in first iteration it will call `find_user(12345)` and store the output in $arg, because output of previous function is argument to next function. So in second iteration `find_last_name` function will be called with argument (result of `find_user(12345)`).

Comment: echo $arg; is the final output after all function call.